# MBR is toast or at least Grub is

Tags: linux, boot, grub, gentoo, chroot

This started after some kernel trouble that I left alone for a while. I had miscompiled a kernel then tried to re-compile it and started to organize a list of boot options in grub for differently configured kernels and vbox threw a fit so I left the computer alone for a while.

Booting it back up now I get 1 of 2 different error messages.

```
grub loading stage 1.5
error 17/18
```

or

```
grub loading stagerror
```

I'm running Gentoo 64bit and I have been updating it through a `chroot` environment

This is on a 2TB drive that I have 1.08TB used that I can not back up
though I have a `tar` image of the root

partition layout is as fallows

```
1    50GB    EXT4    /        10GB   Used    40GB  Free
2    1950GB  EXT4    /home    1.08TB Used    800GB Free
```

Comment: You appear to be using legacy grub, which has been unmaintained and deprecated for several years.  You should upgrade to grub2.

Comment: gentoo has it's own maintained version. They are working on moving to 2.00 but as of now gentoo's stable repo has grub .97-R14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to say what exactly "vbox threw a fit" means, but according to [Gentoo Grub Error Collection](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/grub-error-guide.xml), error 17 is `Cannot mount selected partition`, and error 18 is `Selected cylinder exceeds max supported by BIOS`. Looking at [How to fix GNU Grub error 17?](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080802090632AARQLHB), it looks like this can be caused by a broken GRUB installation, which isn't entirely unreasonable if you have been working in a chroot environment. `grub loading stagerror` (or something similar) also would seem to point in such a direction.

The first thing that I would try is to simply reinstall GRUB. Boot with a rescue CD, mount your root partition, chroot into it, and then reinstall the boot loader. That last part might be as simple as:

```
# grub
grub> root (hd0,0)
grub> setup (hd0)
grub> exit
```

Make sure that the device specifications are correct.

Comment: have done that but it almost seems like it is not installing to the mbr or something. I'm running puppy linux now as a temp solution but I can not chroot from here as puppy is 32bit and my gentoo is 64bit.

Comment: going to boot backtrack and I'll respond after I try this. When I tried before to reinstall grub I just used the auto install ( grub-install ) but maybe this is not working right because of the chroot running on the ubuntu kernel

Comment: vbox throwing a fit is the fact that you have to have it recompile it's modules from the new kernel source and you have to do it before there is a new kernel update or get ready to recompile vbox/copy the binary portion for usb support